# Why Same Values

Tags: python, loops, keras, deep-learning, hyperparameters

I was writing a custom function that takes in a few parameters and returns a tuple which is just a list of values having the history of model training.

It has parameters as `model`, `generator`, `callback` , batch_size list(`bs`) , epoch_list(`ep`) , shape_list(`sh`)
and returns the values as tuples.

which is given by something like `shape_acc = shape_acc.append(h.history["accuracy"])`

As expected it should return different values but when I used this bit of code:

```
b_acc , b_val , e_acc , e_val , s_acc , s_val = check_best_value(model , gen , callback , bs_lis , ep_lis 
                                                                 , tg_lis)

b_acc = np.array(bs_acc) 
print(b_acc)

e_acc = np.array(ep_acc)
print(ep_acc)
```

It returns the **same array of values**

```
[[0.13667651 0.1494592  0.15437561]]
[[0.13667651 0.1494592  0.15437561]]
```

Why is this happening, I think the problem is in the indentation of these lines.

```
            shape_acc = shape_acc.append(h.history["accuracy"])
            shape_val = shape_val.append(h.history["val_accuracy"])

        epoch_acc = epoch_acc.append(h.history["accuracy"])
        epoch_val = epoch_val.append(h.history["val_accuracy"])                

    bs_acc = bs_acc.append(h.history["accuracy"])
    bs_val = bs_val.append(h.history["val_accuracy"])

    return bs_acc , bs_val , epoch_acc , epoch_val , shape_acc , shape_val
```

Can anyone suggest the fix and shed some light? Here is my original code:

```
def check_best_value(model, generator , callback , bs , ep , sh):
    bs_acc = []
    bs_val = []

    epoch_acc = []
    epoch_val = []

    shape_acc = []
    shape_val = []


    callback = EarlyStopping(monitor = 'val_loss' , patience = 1 , verbose = 1 , 
    restore_best_weights=True , mode = 'auto')

    for bs_size in bs:
        for ep_size in ep:
            for img_size in sh:
                train_gen = generator.flow_from_directory(TRAIN_DIR , 
                                                                target_size = (img_size , img_size),
                                                                batch_size = bs_size ,
                                                                class_mode = 'categorical',
                                                                subset = 'training',
                                                                seed = 14)
                
                val_gen = generator.flow_from_directory(TRAIN_DIR , 
                                                                target_size = (img_size , img_size),
                                                                batch_size = bs_size ,
                                                                class_mode = 'categorical',
                                                                subset = 'validation',
                                                                seed = 14)
                h = model.fit(train_gen,
                                steps_per_epoch=train_gen.samples // bs_size,
                                epochs=ep_size,
                                validation_data=val_gen,
                                validation_steps= val_gen.samples // bs_size,
                                callbacks = [callback],
                                verbose=0)
                
            shape_acc = shape_acc.append(h.history["accuracy"])
            shape_val = shape_val.append(h.history["val_accuracy"])

        epoch_acc = epoch_acc.append(h.history["accuracy"])
        epoch_val = epoch_val.append(h.history["val_accuracy"])                

    bs_acc = bs_acc.append(h.history["accuracy"])
    bs_val = bs_val.append(h.history["val_accuracy"])
    
    return bs_acc , bs_val , epoch_acc , epoch_val , shape_acc , shape_val
```

Comment: Seems like you have multiple *references* to the same array whereas at some stage you needed to create *copies*.

Comment: Can u suggest how to do that ? Is there error in those append, what I can do to make it work as expected , any code stub will help :)

Comment: I don't know the library so I don't know what this `h` object actually is, but perhaps things like `epoch_acc = epoch_acc.append(h.history["accuracy"].copy()` might work.

Comment: ```h``` is just history object after using ```model.fit() ```, it has all the training results in it  which can be plotted to find best results for each of given list , I am just using it to do hyper parameter search in order to find best fit